# .focus() jQuery & vanilla js not working on element in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have a  element that I've made focusable through tabindex="0" attribute. These labels contain inputs and are custom checkboxes. The typical functionality between checkboxes and radios in a group is to use the up and down arrow keys to switch between them and space to select.

I am trying to recreate this behavior, which doesn't work because of the nesting within in divs.

I have recreated the behavior with jQuery's `.next()` and `.prev()` to go focus on the next or previous label and focus on it. This works fine in chrome.

It does not work in firefox.

When I log the element that I am selecting (`console.log($(event.target).prev()[0]`) exists and it exists and is the right element. When I try to use `.focus()` on it or wrap it in a jQuery selector and then try jQuery's `.focus()` on it, nothing happens. Only in firefox.

I read somewhere to put it in a setTime delaying after the keyup event, but that doesn't work either.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is a sample of my html:

```
<div class="formify-field-container " id="formify-field-container-537" data-ffid="537" data-field-type="radio" data-rule-count="0" aria-live="assertive" role="alert" data-unmet-rule-count="0" data-rule-action="" data-rule-requirement="" ng-class="(isInValidInput('fiscalAgentCOrSA') ? 'formify-error' : '')">

                <div class="formify-field-input formify-radio ">
                    <fieldset class="formify-fieldset">
                        <div class="formify-legend">Is the district operating as the fiscal agent of a consortium or
                            shared
                            service agreement: <span style="color:#ff0000">*</span>
                        </div>

                        <label data-formify-ffid="537" class="formify-radio-label" for="formify-field-537-0" tabindex="0">
                            <input class="formify-field formify-radio ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" ng-model="formData.fiscalAgentCOrSA" name="fiscalAgentCOrSA" value="1" id="formify-field-537-0" required="" type="radio">
                            <span><i data-formify-ffid="537" class="fa "></i></span>
                            Yes </label>
                        <label data-formify-ffid="537" class="formify-radio-label" for="formify-field-537-1" tabindex="0">
                            <input class="formify-field formify-radio ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" ng-model="formData.fiscalAgentCOrSA" name="fiscalAgentCOrSA" value="0" id="formify-field-537-1" required="" type="radio">
                            <span><i data-formify-ffid="537" class="fa "></i></span>
                            No </label>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
 $('.formify-radio').on('keyup', function(e){
    var event=e||window.event;
    if(event.which===13 || event.which===32){
        $(event.target).find('input').trigger('click');
    }
    if(event.which===38){
        if($(event.target).prev().is('label')) $($(event.target).prev()[0]).focus();
    }
    if(event.which===40){
        if($(event.target).next().is('label')) $($(event.target).next()[0]).focus();
    }
});
```

Update: Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/afxkutvm/

Comment: The jQuery `.prev()` and `.next()` functions are for navigating sibling to sibling. Your radio button elements are children of the `<label>` elements, so the label will *never* be found by `.prev()`

Comment: your jsfiddle works exactly as you described in firefox quantum (once you add jquery to it)

Comment: @Pointy why do you think `event.target` is a label? it's a radio button...

Comment: It is being found because it is the event.target, which is the label. I console.log() the element I am trying to focus on and it is the label. The exact label I need, but when I do .focus(), it doesn't focus.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce., it is the label when I log it. The event on the input propagates to the label.

Comment: whaaaa... `<input class="formify-field formify-radio .......`

Comment: oh, duh, if you click on the words the target is the label..

Comment: you should probably use `this` instead of `event.target` that way you know it will always be the input

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. No, the target will be the `<input>` A `<label>` can't get focus and I would be very surprised if Firefox could be convinced to generate keyboard events from a `<label>` anyway.

Comment: @Pointy - i just logged it, sometimes it's input sometimes it's label. if you change it to `this` sometimes it's a div, sometimes it's a input.... the problem here has something to do with inconsistent use of class names.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. and you're getting that from *keyboard* events?

Comment: @Pointy yes. 1) add jquery to the fiddle. 2) add `console.log(e.target)` to the begining of the function. 3) click on the yes radio button. 4) press up a few times (will be a label consistently) 5) press down a few times, will be a label and an input..  am I missing something?

Comment: the first child div of the outermost parent div also has the same classname

Comment: Since the radio buttons are inside the `<div>` that also has class "formify-radio", a single keyboard event (when I can get Firefox to generate one) triggers the handler twice, as far as I can tell. I *never* see a `<label>` as the target. (I'm in Firefox in Linux. The funny part is that the arrows and space bar do precisely what the OP asked for anyway, for me.)

Comment: @Pointy You're logging the target, not the context, right? If so, and if you clicked on the actual *radio button* and not the words/label surrounding it, the target is, in FF Quantum, the input itself, and it should be. If the input is focused when the keys are pressed then the input would be the target... Like I said, this should really be using `this` instead of `e.target` since the target is whatever dispatched the event but `this` is always going to be the element that's listening for it.

Comment: I'm on FF on Mac and it works exactly like OP requested for me too.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Logging both `this` and `event.target`. I've also changed the selector to be `"input.formify-radio"` to get rid of the `<div>` noise. I only see the `<input>` element in the handler. I can only get the browser to trigger the "keyup" when the radio is checked.

Comment: @Pointy That doesn't work: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/eaef7fa30bf0f5b45d386dc285e4fbf8 I probably should've pointed out that the inputs are display:none so they can't be focused on and therefore no keyup events. But the labels are custom styled checkboxes. Every event that happens to the label should happen to the corresponding input that has the id that matches its for attribute. So I can't use the input as the selector. I was using the label. So we're back at square one. Any ideas?